# Use query results in another sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

please help as this is turning into a week of almost no sleep already..

I have a table called Products, 
with these columns: id | productName | category | subcategory | date_added | price .

how can I get the ID and category from the LAST PRODUCT ADDED IN EACH SUBCATEGORY in this table?

so far this kinda works but it only returns the subcategory, and I also need the category and ID

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12");
```

If i try something like

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id, category, subcategory FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12");
```

it just returns everything..

Thank you all

Comment: Have a sub-query that returns last product for each sub-category. Join with that result.

Comment: provide your table structure with sample data's

Comment: **don't** use `mysql_`-functions, they are outdated, deprecated, and in PHP7 removed. use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: @NewbeeDev the first line of his post haha, he needs some sleep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: group them by subcategory

```
GROUP  BY subcategory
```

then set your condition to `id = (select your id of latest product according to its subcategory)`

```
id = (SELECT id 
         FROM   products 
         WHERE  products.subcategory = Product.subcategory 
         ORDER  BY created DESC 
         LIMIT  1)
```

So your query would be like this

```
SELECT * 
    FROM   products Product 
    WHERE  id = (SELECT id 
                 FROM   products 
                 WHERE  products.subcategory = Product.subcategory 
                 ORDER  BY created DESC 
                 LIMIT  1) 
GROUP  BY subcategory
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Mate, what you have done here was way beyond my expectations  :))) Thank you, you have saved me! you understood the entire problem better than anyone that I've asked before .. and the tables and everything.. pfff.. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `products` GROUP BY subcategory ORDER By id DESC
```

**MySQL extension is deprecated and removed from php7 so use mysqli or PDO**

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
SELECT id, category, subcategory FROM products GROUP BY (subcategory) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 0):

if `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM `products` GROUP BY subcategory)
```